# Unexpected symbol error in parse(text = str) with hyphen after a digit

Tags: r, parsing

I am trying to parse a character string in R. 
R throws an "unexpected symbol" or "unexpected end of input" exception when there is a digit followed by a hyphen in the string (please see the code). Searching and trying different ways to solve this issue didn't help. 
Probably some lack of knowledge in my part. 
Any help or advise would be highly appreciated.

```
> str <- "abc12-3def"
> parse(text = str)
Error in parse(text = str) : <text>:1:8: unexpected symbol
1: abc12-3def
          ^
```

or

```
> str <- "abc123-"
> parse(text = str)
Error in parse(text = str) : <text>:2:0: unexpected end of input
1: abc123-
  ^
```

However, following examples all work normally

```
> str <- "abc123def"
> parse(text = str)
expression(abc123def)
```

or

```
> str <- "abc123-def"
> parse(text = str)
expression(abc123-def)
```

or

```
> str <- "abc12-3"
> parse(text = str)
expression(abc12-3)
```

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 16):

You can easily reproduce the `parse` behavior with :

```
str <- "3a"
parse(text = str)
```

`parse` try to parse your str as a variable name. Or, you should give an available variable name, either it should not begin with a digit or you should put it between ``. the following works :

```
str <- "`3a`"
parse(text = str)
```

and in your example , this works also :

```
str <- "abc12-`3def`"
parse(text = str)
```

Finally for your second example , it is logic that it will not work since you don't give an available expression to parse:

```
str <- "abc123-"  ## this will like myvar-
```

if your `-` is just a string separator, why not to transform it to `_`? for example:

```
 parse(text=gsub('-','_',str))
```

Comment: Thank you for the prompt response. Concerning your example, str <- "abc12-`3def`", I need a string without backquotes. Anyway, thank you, I am starting to see the logic now.

Comment: @agstudy  can you please explain in layman terms on why there was error when string has - or say ( ?

Answer (score 4):

The point of `parse` is to turn your input text into an R-language expression. Just as if you typed

```
abc12-3def
```

at the R prompt, it would throw a syntax error, so too will `parse`. You can't just throw arbitrary text at it and assume it'll give you something sensible.

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately, my reputation is not enough to mark both the above answers as useful.

Answer (score 0):

if you have a hyphen in the string, the same error continues with `facet_wrap()` in ggplot2.

I have code
`facet_wrap(~ID.new, scales = "fixed", ncol = 1, labeller = label_parsed)+`

and ID.new is like `T001_01_2023_10_26_16_19_44.CSV~italic(n) == 9506`

The error is below:

> Error in parse(text = as.character(values)) :
> :1:19: unexpected input
> 1: T001_01_2023-10-26_

I solved the issue using `gsub()` when creating the new ID.

`mutate(ID.new = paste0(gsub('-','_',ID), "~italic(n)", " == ", n))`

All code is here:

```
d <- all.rr.df[!is.na(all.rr.df$Time),] %>%
    add_count(ID) %>%
    # Here,  Hyphens ("-") can be used in this context, but they need to be replaced with underscores ("_") in ID!
    mutate(ID.new = paste0(gsub('-','_',ID), "-"," ~italic(n)", " == ", n))


all.rr_plot <- ggplot(d, aes(Time,RR, group = ID)) +
          geom_line(linetype = 1, color = "red", size = 0.5) +
          geom_smooth(method = lm)+
        facet_wrap(~ID.new, scales = "fixed", ncol = 1, labeller = label_parsed) +
```

[image]