# R Shiny: Unclear error within lm function (parse)

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to do a regression by having a user select the factors to include in their model. However, I get an error when I have the code embedded within Shiny:

```
library(shiny)
shinyApp(
    ui = fluidPage(
        sidebarLayout(
        uiOutput(outputId="factorcheckboxes"),
        mainPanel(
        textOutput("regression")
        )
    )), 
server = function(input, output) {
    regr <- function(){
        matx<-data.frame(Factor1=c(1,5,6),Factor2=c(2,4,5),Response=c(1,2,3))
        mainfactors<-paste(sprintf("`%s`",input$factors),collapse="+")
        responsefac<-sprintf("%s",colnames(matx)[length(colnames(matx))])
        regr.lm<-lm(formula=sprintf("`%s`~%s",responsefac,mainfactors),data=matx)
        regr.lm$coefficients[1]
    }

    output$regression <- renderText({
        regr()
    })

    output$factorcheckboxes <- renderUI({
    {
        checkboxGroupInput(inputId="factors",
        label="Main Factors:",
        choices=c("Factor1","Factor2"), selected=c("Factor1","Factor2"), inline=FALSE)
    }
    })
})
```

The error is clearly related to the parse function...

```
Error in parse(text = x, keep.source = FALSE) : 
  <text>:2:0: unexpected end of input
1: `Response`~
   ^
```

... so following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17639325/unexpected-symbol-error-in-parsetext-str-with-hyphen-after-a-digit) advice, I made sure that the tilde (~) character was outside of the `responsefac` string. But it appears I am still getting an error.

This appears to work, which is the same code except `c("Factor1","Factor2")` is in place of `input$factors`:

```
matx<-data.frame(Factor1=c(1,5,6),Factor2=c(2,4,5),Response=c(1,2,3))
mainfactors<-paste(sprintf("`%s`",c("Factor1","Factor2")),collapse="+")
responsefac<-sprintf("%s",colnames(matx)[length(colnames(matx))])
regr.lm<-lm(formula=sprintf("`%s`~%s",responsefac,mainfactors),data=matx)
regr.lm$coefficients[1]
```

However, I would need the input$factors functionality within the Shiny code.

Comment: Arguments to 'formula' as a named argument need to be formula-objects, not just text. (You may also need to specify an environment for evaluation.)

Comment: Also : It's generally a bad idea to use `$` as an indexing function inside functions. Use "[[" instead.

Comment: Could you please expand on how I would call a formula-object as opposed to text? Also, I'm a bit confused on your second point - `regr.lm[[coefficients[1]]]` doesn't work and neither does `input.factors`.

Comment: See `?as.formula` although I'm not sure that explains your error. You might also run `traceback()` to see which functions were being called in the lead up to the error. I was surprises to see backticks in the error message. Sometimes using `as.name` will solve difficulties with character objects not being language objects.