# parse string with numbers or hyphens as one string in R

Tags: r, parsing

I am trying to parse strings with hyphens and/or numbers to call specific rows.

```
gene_name <- c("EP-CAM")
Genename=paste0("RNA$",gene_name)
Gene=eval(parse(text = paste0(Genename)))
```

This is the error:

```
Error in eval(parse(text = paste0(Genename))) : 
  object 'CAM' not found
```

I would need to get RNA$EP-CAM parsed for example. Backquotes will not give me the output and only show me the string.

With numbers the same would happen. I guess this is just a problem of the parse command. Is there an alternative to it?
This is in analogy to this problem: [Unexpected symbol error in parse(text = str) with hyphen after a digit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17639325/unexpected-symbol-error-in-parsetext-str-with-hyphen-after-a-digit?rq=1)

Thank you so much for you support.

D

Comment: Am I correct that you are trying to access the variable `EP-CAM` from the object `RNA`?

Comment: exactly RNA$EP-CAM or simultaniously from numbers RNA$2EP-CAM to get all possibilities in there.

Comment: Dashes are not allowed (or rather they get parsed as minus-signs, hence that perticular error) in unquoted R names.

Answer (score 2):

Adding back ticks to the call works for me. The problem, here, is that "EP-CAM" isn't really a valid name.

```
RNA <- list(`EP-CAM` = 0)
gene <- c("EP-CAM")
geneName <- paste0("RNA$`", gene, "`")
eval(parse(text = geneName))
# [1] 0
```

In fact, the following renames the column as `EP.CAM`.

```
data.frame(`EP-CAM` = 0)
#   EP.CAM
# 1      0
```

Comment: You can avoid the renaming by giving `data.frame` the `check.names = FALSE` argument. If you do that, your solution works with data.frames too

Comment: thanks this did the job. only question in my example later I do transpose the table. initially I had it with chech.names=FALSE but for the above example if I transpose t(data.frame(`EP-CAM` =0, check.names=FALSE)) it will change "-" to "." any idea?

Comment: Is there a reason you need the hyphen in your variable names? Using an illegal variable name is going to make everything you do much harder. I would **strongly** recommend replacing hyphens with a legal character like the underscore `_` or period `.`

Comment: I agree. However, `t(data.frame(``EP-CAM`` = 0, check.names = FALSE))` works for me (obviously, only using single back-ticks.