# parse in geom_label : ERROR while rich displaying an object: Error in parse(text = text[[i]])=

Tags: r, ggplot2, text-parsing

I print a `geom_label` using `ggplot` with the following code :

```
ggplot()+
    geom_label(aes( x = 10, y = 0.545, label = " expression 1 =  p-value = 9.19 e-09 ; CI : [0.00, 0.00]"), 
             label.size = NA , hjust =0.08, size = 3.5, family = "Helvetica")
```

and **I am trying to print the `p` in *italic***.
So I have tried

```
ggplot()+
    geom_label(aes( x = 10, y = 0.545, label = " expression 1 =  p-value = 9.19 e-09 ; CI : [0.00, 0.00]"), 
             label.size = NA , hjust =0.08, size = 3.5, family = "Helvetica")+
    geom_label(aes( x = 10, y = 0.509, label = paste("expression 2 =  italic(p)-value = 9.19 e-09 ; CI : [0.00, 0.00]")), 
             label.size = NA, hjust =0.08, size = 3.5, family = "Helvetica", parse = T)
```

Which return me the folloing error message :

> ERROR while rich displaying an object: Error in parse(text =
> text[[i]]): :1:19: unexpected string constant 1: 'expression 1 :
> ' 'italic(p)'

Do you know where the error come from and how to solve it ?

PS : Based on this post [Unexpected symbol error in parse(text = str) with hyphen after a digit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17639325/unexpected-symbol-error-in-parsetext-str-with-hyphen-after-a-digit),
I also tried

```
ggplot()+
    geom_label(aes( x = 10, y = 0.545, label = " expression 1 =  p-value = 9.19 e-09 ; CI : [0.00, 0.00]"), 
             label.size = NA , hjust =0.08, size = 3.5, family = "Helvetica")+
    geom_label(aes( x = 10, y = 0.509, label = paste("'expression 2 =  italic(p)-value = 9.19 e-09 ; CI : [0.00, 0.00]'")), 
             label.size = NA, hjust =0.08, size = 3.5, family = "Helvetica", parse = T)
```

which works but returns me this
[image: res]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Study `help("plotmath")`.

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot()+
  geom_label(aes(x = 10, y = 0.545, 
                 label = " expression 1 =  p-value = 9.19 e-09 ; CI : [0.00, 0.00]"), 
             label.size = NA , hjust =0.08, size = 3.5)+
  geom_label(aes(x = 10, y = 0.509, 
                 label = paste("'expression 2 = ' *  italic(p) * '-value = 9.19 e-09 ; CI : [0.00, 0.00]'")), 
             label.size = NA, hjust =0.08, size = 3.5, parse = T)
```

I have removed `family = "Helvetica"` because it caused warnings on my system.