# how to call variables while variable names was stored as a string

Tags: r

If I have a df and I would like to arrange it by 3 variables: "ID, AGE, SEX". How can I call them when I store those three variables' name in a variable "order_var"

```
order_var <- "ID, AGE, SEX"

df %>% arrange (paste0 (order_var))
```

How can  I call those three variables?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use dynamic name for new column/variable in \`dplyr\`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26003574/use-dynamic-name-for-new-column-variable-in-dplyr)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one option - split the 'order_var' at the `,` followed by any space (`\\s*`), extract the list element (`[[1]]`), and pass it inside `across` with `all_of`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   arrange(across(all_of(strsplit(order_var, ",\\s*"))[[1]]))
```

Or another option is `eval` by creating the full expression

```
 eval(rlang::parse_expr(sprintf('df %%>%% arrange(%s)', order_var)))
```

Comment: Do you think `eval` and/or `parse` can be used for this case? I am not familiar with these. Just a thought. Thanks.

Comment: @Stataq Yes, the updated one with eval/parse_expr or `eval(parse(text = sprintf('df %%>%% arrange(%s)', order_var)))`

Comment: I original tried `arrange( eval(parse(paste0(order_var))))`. it must be wrong. could you tell me what did I do wrong if it is possible?

Comment: @Stataq there are multiple issues in that statement  i.e.`parse(text = `, but even then it returns error because of the `,`..  You can also check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17639325/unexpected-symbol-error-in-parsetext-str-with-hyphen-after-a-digit)

Comment: It looks like `across()` must only be used inside dplyr verbs. What if I want to use in `compareDF::compare_df` and its `group_col=`?

Comment: @Stataq can you show an example

Comment: sth like `compareDF::compare_df(
      df_new , df_old , group_col = cross(all_of(strsplit(order_var, ",\\s*"))[[1]]), stop_on_error = FALSE    )`

Comment: why do you use `cross` and `all_of`, does `group_col = strsplit(order_var, ",\\s*")[[1]]` works?

Comment: i.e. `order_var <- "gear, carb"; compare_df(head(mtcars), head(mtcars, 10), group_col = strsplit(order_var, ",\\s*")[[1]])` works for me

Comment: what if I want to use `eval(parse..` for this case?

Comment: @Stataq that would be `eval(parse(text = sprintf("compare_df(head(mtcars), head(mtcars, 10), group_col = c(%s))", gsub('(\\w+)', '"\\1"', order_var))))`